# Disable multiple instances of onSubmit trigger during submissions

Tags: google-apps-script, locking, google-forms

I have a form with onSubmit trigger, Which will be used as an domain wide add - on.The add - on can be used
for many forms.
I need to disable the multiple submit triggers, instead run only 1 instance currently.
Say the form submissions arrive at same time, I need to avoid the duplicate instances of the script running when the current script is running.
I tried to use lock service

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    // lock the document response
    var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
    if (lock.hasLock()) return;
    //do some tasks
    lock.releaseLock();
}
```

How do I make a script (addon) to run as a single instance.

**UPDATE: This code too, doesnt achive the intended functionality**

```
function OnSubmits(e) {
    var releaseLock;

    releaseLock = function() {
        lock.releaseLock();

    }

    var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
    lock.tryLock(1);
    if (!lock.hasLock()) {
        return;
    }
    var value = cUseful.Utils.expBackoff(function() {
        releaseLock();
        return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('key');
    });
    if (value == null) value = 0;
    else value++;
    cUseful.Utils.expBackoff(function() {
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1wFGMh38JGarJd8CaiaOynlB7iiL_Pw6D");
        folder.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.create('Document Name ' + value).getId()));
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('key', value);
    });

    releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `LockService` work?

Comment: Use atomic operations like `Sheet#appendRow` to deal with high traffic.

Comment: If LockService is not working for the amount of submissions that you are getting, then you'll need to do the tasks after the Form submission has already been saved.  You'd need to use a time based trigger, or when the "On Form Submit" trigger runs, process all pending submissions up to the run-time quota limit, and then when the next "On Form Submit" trigger runs do it all over again.

Comment: Thank you @Sandy Good it would be of great help help if you could share a small snippet, as this is needed for an internal domain wide addon. How do I know the remaining or pending unprocessed without using spreadsheet? Since many responses arrive, how do I avoid collision, since all may try to compete for processing of the remaining at the same time. I do not want to use spreadsheet. The basic idea is to act like an add-on form publisher.

Comment: You release the lock when acquiring `value`... Only release it when you are done setting it. Also note that your script will simply ignore any submissions that fail to get a lock. That's probably not your intent.

Comment: If you don't want to use a spreadsheet, then you need a question in the Form to mark whether that submission has been processed or not.  And you'll need to hide that question from the users, because you don't want them to answer that question.  Then the code will need to find the first un-processed submission, and process it.  Then look for the next unprocessed submission, until the code doesn't find anymore un-processed submissions.  A Google Form is sort of a database, but it has no search capability other than `getResponses(timestamp)` by timestamp.  Search by timestamp of submission first.

Comment: You are right @tehhowch . Can you show me how we modify the code not to ignore instead process the next waiting? Is it possible?

Comment: Use a longer wait than 1 second. And then if you still didn't get the lock, store the response id somewhere, and periodically run your task function for those stored IDs. Note that for a high-frequency function, `PropertiesService` will start to be the limiting resource. Consider abstracting the `value` getter and setter to helper functions that take a key and use both Cache and Properties.

Comment: Any code help please?